# Unable to mock WebConfigurationManager.GetSection using MoQ

Tags: c#, moq

I am trying to mock WebConfigurationManager.GetSection.

In my C# code I have this:

```
 public string ContentManagerServicePassword = ((System.Configuration.NameValueConfigurationCollection)WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("contentManagerSecurePassword"))["password"].Value;
```

In my test class I am trying this:

```
var mockIConfiguration = new Mock<IConfiguration>();
var mockIConfigurationSection = new Mock<IConfigurationSection>();
mockIConfigurationSection.Setup(x => x.Key).Returns("contentManagerSecurePassword");
mockIConfigurationSection.Setup(x => x.Value).Returns("password:abcdcdvf");
mockIConfiguration.Setup(x 
=>x.GetSection("contentManagerSecurePassword")).Returns(mockIConfigurationSection.Object);
```

On debugging my test WebConfigurationManager is null.

Appreciate any inputs on this for me to proceed.

Regards,
Sajesh

Comment: `WebConfigurationManager` is a static class. You can't mock it. All you can do is modify your code not to depend on it, which isn't bad anyway. I tried to create an answer but it's really a broad subject and I'd have to make guesses about your code. The short version is to use dependency injection to supply that value to the class that needs it. That way you can test the class without testing `WebConfigurationManager`. The class that needs the password shouldn't also read it from config or know where it comes from. Everything is easier when you keep those things separate.

Comment: Yea i agree Scott..its an old code and I have to refactor the complete code now

Comment: Yah the best you're going to get now is to expose your own wrapper class and interface around the configuration. Obviously it would just call in to the static class methods. But at least then you'd be able to swap it out with something else later